# Change line color of .table-bordered in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am styling a number of tables with twitter bootstrap and am using the `.table.table-bordered` class. The default border color is gray, which is good for all my tables except one. For one table, I would like to change this border color to black and also make the lines thicker if possible. I am using less.

I've researched it and found the `@tableBorder` variable which I can customize but changing this changes the color of all the tables.

I tried giving the table a class and putting this in the css file:

```
.differentTable {
   @tableBorder: black;
}
```

...but that did not seem to change anything (not sure why).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're only changing the variable within that context, but you're not applying it. You'll have to copy the property that is using @tableBorder.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@tableBorder` is a variable, not a property.

You can just add this to your CSS:

```
.differentTable, .differentTable td{
   border-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The best way is

```
.table {
  border: 0.5px solid #000000;
}
.table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
   border: 0.5px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: Still the best answer

Answer (score 4):

```
.table-bordered td, .table-bordered th{
    border-color: black !important;
}
```

.table-bordered th : create border for head and foot table.

.table-bordered td : create border for body table

I have to use '!important', because the border wouldn't change without it.

Comment: This answer would benefit from a little bit of elaboration, explanation and reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css property in addition with bootstrap class .table and .table-bordered.

```
<style>

th,td{
border-color: black !important;
border: 2px solid black;
}

</style>
```

**Note:** !important is must as borders won't change their colour without it.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has colored border specific by it's own.

just use `class="border border-dark"` for the table td,th you want to highlight it.

other pre-defined colors in bootstrap also work for `border-*` too, use some help [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_utilities.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This the best way

```
.table-border,
thead,
tbody,
tr {
  border: 5px dotted #4c4c4c;
}
```

change border-style property in bootstrap.